# Fixin .csv file in R to avoid "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Tags: r, date, csv

I'm trying to identify the week number from the date variable in the csv file.
Most of the column values have the correctly assigned date, e.g. "2006-03-23 11:11:22"
which is correctly interpreted by R:

```
> strftime(as.POSIXlt("2006-03-23 11:11:22"), format="%W")
[1] "12"
```

However, some values are assigned 0 values - i.e. "0000-00-00 00:00:00", which are interpreted incorrectly.

```
> strftime(as.POSIXlt("0000-00-00 00:00:00"), format="%W")
Error in as.POSIXlt.character("0000-00-00 00:00:00") : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

What can I do with my csv file to fix it? The file is very large and I need smth efficient

Comment: what do you want done with the 0000-00-00 00:00:00 dates? left out? set to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `tryCatch`. For example

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c(rep("2006-03-23 11:11:22", 3), rep("0000-00-00 00:00:00", 3)))
df$Week <- apply(df, 1, function(x) tryCatch(strftime(as.POSIXlt(x), format="%W"), error = function(e) ""))
df

                 Date Week
1 2006-03-23 11:11:22   12
2 2006-03-23 11:11:22   12
3 2006-03-23 11:11:22   12
4 0000-00-00 00:00:00     
5 0000-00-00 00:00:00     
6 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

For a very big dataset you can speed it up by using all of your cores using `parApply`
Two cores example:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
df$Week <- parApply(cl, df, 1, function(x) tryCatch(strftime(as.POSIXlt(x), format="%W"), error = function(e) ""))
```